# i work in a angular broject and the npm run server is not working

Tags: angular, npm, cmd, server

(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\home>cd 3-services
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\home>cd 3-services

C:\Users\home\3-services>cd 3-services

C:\Users\home\3-services\3-services>npm run server

> angular-course@0.0.0 server
> ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -P ./server.tsconfig.json ./server.ts

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\home\3-services\3-services>

Answer (score 0):

Set the nodejs path in environment of your PC.

1. Search for Environment Variables in the Windows search
2. Edit the System environment variables" option will be popped in the result
3. Open that, select the "Path" and click on edit, then click "New" add your
   nodeJS Bin path i.e in my machine its installed in

   ```
   c:\programfiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
   ```
4. Once you added click "Ok" then close

Now you can write your command in prompt or PowerShell.

Sometime it's required to restart the PC.